# Diagnostic aggregator not resetting between runs

Tags: ros, diagnostics, diagnostic-aggregator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having a problem that the diagnostic aggregator contains analyzers from a previous run. The situation is this:

1. Start roscore
2. Start an application, including diagnostic aggreggator, using roslaunch
3. Stop the application and launch another one with a new yaml-file
4. The aggregator message now contains analyzers from both the new and the old application (the old ones are stale now of cource).

The problem arises when having roscore running and starting different applications with roslaunch (so skipping step one would fix the problem). The reason I start roscore is that I have a GUI that can start (and close down) different applications. This GUI is a rosnode, so I have to have roscore running while starting and stopping other applications.

Is there a way of resetting the aggregator so it just listens to new messages (the ones specified specified in the last yaml-file loaded)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11986/diagnostic-aggregator-not-resetting-between-runs/) by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2011-11-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out how to solve this problem. By deleting "diagnostic_aggregator" from the parameter server when closing an application, only the the nodes specified in the new yaml-file will show when starting a new application.

---

Originally posted by [Ola Ringdahl](https://answers.ros.org/users/1011/ola-ringdahl/) with karma: 328 on 2011-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0